# Pycharm subprocess call not finding installed software

Tags: python, pycharm, subprocess

This post was heavily edited to make the question clearer

I have installed a program called blast on my debian system
When I run the following code inside pycharm (shift-10)

```
import subprocess
ls_out = subprocess.check_output("ls /usr/bin/ | grep ^b", shell=True)  # list and I only show files/folders starting with the letter b
print(ls_out.decode("utf-8"))
```

it does not find my program
when I run the same script in the shell:

```
$ python3 ./test_pycharm.py
```

It does (I can put the outputs here but they take a lot of space)

Can someone explain what's happening here? Why can pycharm only find the pre-installed programs and not the ones I installed myself?
Is this something linux does? like a system link?

Comment: Your initial code shows 'executable="\bin\bash"  which, iiuc, is not valid in debian.  Have you tried executable="/bin/bash"?

Comment: Woops, I wrote it down wrongly in my question, I used "/bin/bash"

Comment: Isn't `/bin/bash` a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/bash` or even more `/usr/bin/dash` in debian ? Have you tried to original path ?

Comment: I took it out. See the revised post. I also tried changing the path to no avail